# Passing a generic definition of a collection as a type parameter - or how to use "List<>" as a type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0

I'll try to be as straight-forward as possible.

I want to be able to do something like this:

```
var mylookup = new ModifiableLookup<MyClass, int, List<> >();
var myhashlookup = new ModifiableLookup<MyClass, int, HashSet<> >();
```

While having a generic class along this lines:

```
class ModifiableLookup<TKey, TElement, TElementCollection<> > : ILookup<TKey, TElement>
    where TElementCollection<> : ICollection<TElement>, new()
{
    private Dictionary<TKey, TElementCollection<TElement> > data;
    /// ... so on and so forth
}
```

But Alas, this does not work...

The work-around is to repeat the type parameter:

```
var mylookup = new ModifiableLookup<MyClass, int, List<int> >();
///...
class ModifiableLookup<TKey, TElement, TElementCollection> : ILookup<TKey, TElement>
    where TElementCollection : ICollection<TElement>, new()
```

---

Is there a way to accomplish something like this without repeating the collection element type parameter and without using reflection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible within your constraints. Open generic types can only appear as parameters to the `typeof` operator. They are not permitted anywhere else in your source.